# Why I can't apply IF condition in email_verified_at field in Blade

Tags: laravel, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

**Controller**

```
 $userAlbums =album::select('album_id')->where('created_by','=',Auth::id())->count();
 $userData = user::where('id','=',Auth::id())->first();
 return view('welcome', compact('userData','userAlbums'));
```

**Blade**

```
@if($userData->email_varified_at == null)
@include('include.email-verification')
@endif
```

if i try to display $userData->email_varified_at variable it works ,but the IF condition also run every time  even if email_varified_at field is not null.

is this have any thing to do with casting of filed?

Comment: `varified` is misspelled in your field name. It may just be a typo in your question, but make sure your field name in your code matches the field name in the database, otherwise it'll always be null.

Comment: as patricus says, `varified` is not `verified` ... if you try to access an attribute that does not exist on a Model instance you get `null`

Comment: oh my god , thank you so much , i forgot check was spelling  this took my whole day.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the empty function?

```
@if( !empty($str->a))
... // do somethin
@endif
```

The empty() function checks whether a variable is empty or not.

This function returns false if the variable exists and is not empty, otherwise it returns true.

The following values evaluate to empty:

0

0.0

"0"

""

NULL

FALSE

array()

Comment: no still load view under if condition even if veriable is not empty  ( i used if(empty($veriuable)){then load}   )